# Fresh Install of 14.04 Ubuntu Server, failing to achieve Ethernet connection under 2 switches

Tags: networking, server, connection

Old laptop with a fresh install of Ubuntu Server 14.04 is failing to achieve an Ethernet connection when connected to a 5 port switch. I know this switch works as I've connected other computers with Ubuntu Server 14.04 to it and my main windows computer to it.

Hardware topography: WAN -> Router(w/switch) -> 24port switch -> 5 port switch ->Computer with problem

When I do the command

```
sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces
```

I get:

```
auto lo 
iface lo inet loopback
```

When I do:

```
ifconfig -a
```

3 Devices are listed, lo (presumably the loopback virtual thing), p5p1 (this is the ethernet device, note it's not named eth0) and wlan0 (wireless device)
None of them apart from lo have an IP/connection.

Restarting Networking services and putting p5p1 up and down does nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the Terminal with the key combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and edit your `/etc/default/grub`:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

Add this line at the end:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="net.ifnames=0 biosdevname=0"
```

Update the grub:

```
sudo update-grub
```

and then restart Ubuntu.

Now, open your `/etc/network/interfaces` and add

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

Finally, restart network

```
sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help, I've done everything you've said, however still no connection. 'ifconfig -a' displays a deviced named eth0 rather than p5p1.

Comment: OK, at least now it got displayed `eth0`. I'll update my answer then.

Comment: Did everything, still no connection. Tried a reboot and noticed its taking much longer to boot because it's "Waiting up to 60 more seconds for network configuration...". Again Thanks for your help.

Comment: Noticed you changed what you had entered to put into /etc/network/interfaces. I changed it to that. I do seem to get given an IP now however I can't seem to connect to the internet (can't ping, or apt-get update). When I connect directly to the 24 port switch though rather than the 5 port switch I can access the internet.  So it sort of fixed it but I'd really rather have it connected under the 5 port switch

Comment: Ok what kind of your 5-port switch? Did you plug it to the 24 with them port?

Comment: Sorry your second question was a bit unclear. It's a DGS-1005A switch, http://www.dlink.co.nz/home-solutions/5-port-gigabit-desktop-switch 
I connected the ubuntu server to the 24 port switch and it gets a connection. When I connect to the 5 port switch which is connected to the 24 port switch it gets given an IP but cannot access the internet

Comment: Does another computer work when connect to the 5 port?

Comment: Yes I currently have a win10 PC connected to the 5 port switch.

Comment: Ok try to ping 8.8.8.8 and if it works check the content of `/etc/resolv.conf`. If possible show it to me.

Comment: Pinging 8.8.8.8 gives: "connect: Network is unreachable"

Comment: OK what IP did `eth0` receive? Is it an IP address in your internal IP subnet?

Comment: Seem to have lost the IP and connection when connected to 24 port switch but now it's back. When connected directly to 24 port switch, IP is 192.168.1.66,  which is under local subnet of 255.255.255.0.  When connected to 5 port switch the IP is also the same. Even though my other win10PC has the same IP. So obviously ubuntu server isn't liking this particular switch...

Comment: it received the same IP with both switches, so it's strange not to work. Do you know if there is any mac address filtering in the 5-port one?

Comment: Not that I know of. It's a basic thing, I don't think I can configure anything in it. Only plug stuff into it. The product website says it has a "An 8,000 MAC address table" if that's of any use.

Comment: Okay well I gave up trying to get it work under 2 switches, your help has gotten to work under at least 1 switch so thanks!.

Comment: You are welcome. Ubuntu maybe incompatible with your 5-port switch. I am quite sad because could not help you completely overcome the issue. Feel free to ping me if you encounter any other issue.